# git server use redmine, fatal: url not valid: is this a git repository?

Tags: git, repository, redmine

```
git --version
git version 1.8.4.2
```

git Server : `redmine`

When I use `git clone username@gitServerUrl`

I got a error messege:

```
fatal: username@gitServerUrl/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: I assume you are using a correct gitServerURL, right??

Comment: yes, the gitServerURL is right, I downgrade git version to 1.7.x, I can clone success

Comment: I think you are cloning from a bare repo. In which case, did you run `git update-server-info` on them server?